# Is a market-tracking leveraged ETF more reward for same risk?

Tags: united-states, investing, stock-markets, leveraged-etf

Due to the way gains compound on one another, and the daily resetting of leveraged ETFs, a 3x ETF will yield MORE than 3x of the underlying asset (in a bullish market), sometimes up to 10x gains in a yearly period.

This makes the long-term investment look *very tempting*, but any reward should come with risk, correct?

I've investigated the risks (risks associated with holding LETFs long-term), and have debunked a few of them myself:

- **In a stagnant market, a leveraged etf is subject to volatility drag and higher management fees**, however the market has not been stagnant in the last 100 years. Any period of stagnation is short-lived, and similar to the principle of value investing, we would be looking to hold the asset for *more than 5 years*. Any sort of loss over some period (say 10% loss over 5 stagnant years) will be received again by only a 3.3% upswing in the underlying asset. I feel like this "risk" is sort of moot.
- **If the tracked asset falls 33% in a day, the fund will be wiped out (assuming 3x etf)** If we invest in a broad-reach etf (SPXL, TQQQ) we would effectively eliminate this risk, because the underlying asset, being the market, will need to fall 33% but there are limits on the US market so that the market cannot fall more than 20% in a single trading day. (See [trading curb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trading_curb) ). Since LETFs re-balance each trading day, multiple -20% days will still never result in the LETF being "wiped out".
- **If the underlying asset falls, a significant portion of the investment will be lost** Underlying assets tend to rebound. If there is a drop of 10%, the asset tends to recover by at least 11% in the future and considerably more. Assuming the underlying asset is the market (i.e. SPY, QQQ, NDAQ), it has always recovered and exceeded previous highs. Therefore this risk contributes more to **timing** than anything -- if I know I need to pull money out in exactly 5 months, the market could be down, but assuming I don't have a need to pull the money out at any specific point in time (withdraw either 5yr, 6yr, 10yr.. all are valid), I mitigate the risk of withdrawing during a low market, eliminating losses here.
- **Diversification is important so do not put all your money in one stock** Something like the SPXL or TQQQ will track a diverse market, therefore diversification is built in.

With all of this, a 3x ETF tracking the market (SPXL, TQQQ) sounds like a clear winner. Historical records show a **15,000% gain over 11 years** on TQQQ. If prior performance is any indicator of future performance then this would be an obvious choice.

Why is it that there is so much advice out there saying that I should **not** hold my money in a leveraged etf long term, what risks are they referring to that have not been covered, and is this a wise or foolish decision to put a significant portion of a portfolio into SPXL or TQQQ, compared to the underlying index (the market, which is generally considered a good investment)?

EDIT: the "market" referenced here is the US market

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Investing in a leveraged index ETF for retirement.  Risky?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/11637/investing-in-a-leveraged-index-etf-for-retirement-risky)

Comment: Many of the leveraged ETFs I can see on my platform were wiped out in March 2020. They will probably never ever recover to their previous prices. YMMV.

Comment: @user253751  ?? How about the leveraged ETFs that were actually suggested in the post? TQQQ recovered to previous highs last July, and SPXL this January. You are feeling awesome today even if you bought into either one last February.

Comment: @OrangeCoast-reinstateMonica thank you, but no it does not answer the question. It reiterates the bolded risks that I have outlined above, but does not speak to the propensity of my stated risk-mitigations, nor outline any new risks not mentioned already.

Comment: @KevinArlin Why stop at 3x?

Comment: @user253751 Well, one good reason is that no ETFs at a higher leverage exist, as far as I know.

Comment: @KevinArlin As previously mentioned, no ETFs exist greater than 3x. I think this had something to do with the crash of 2008 and new regulations put a limit on the amount of leverage allowed in these funds.

Comment: @TylerM Ah, well apparently here in Europe there are 8x and 12x funds available. The trading platform I've used won't let you buy them without taking a test to show you are aware of the significant risk. Anyway, in March 2020, the 12x NASDAQ ETF dropped from about $200.00 per share, down to about $0.10. Not sure if this is a new incarnation now, because it should've been worth zero. Current share price around $15ish. That might be made up eventually, or it might not. If the NASDAQ crashes severely tomorrow, it may well go back down to $0.10.

Comment: @user253751 Well, yes, 12x leverage is obviously too much to hold long term since an 8% move in the underlying is enough to kill you.

Comment: @KevinArlin then what is the optimal amount of leverage? How do you know 3x isn't too much even though a 33.4% move in the underlying is enough to "kill" you? (losing your gambling money is not murder)

Comment: @user253751 i would think the "optimal" amount, in the US market, might be a 4.999x leverage. Technically if the market can fall 20% before it hits daily limits (and effectively shuts down in that day), then a 20% dive would wipe out the fund if it is 5x. Since 4.999x probably won't ever exist, I would pose that a 4x would be the next best option on the US market, since it can't be wiped out by a market freefall

Comment: @user253751 I don't know what the optimal leverage factor is for most young reasonably secure people, but I'm pretty sure it's between 1.5x and 5x. Thanks for helping me out with understanding that metaphors are not literal, by the way! I always find that's so hard for me.

Comment: @TylerM Surely if a 5x fund gets wiped out you may as well write it off and buy into the next 5x fund - what difference does it make whether you have $0 left over, or $0.0002?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding downside of triple-leveraged ETF](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/51821/understanding-downside-of-triple-leveraged-etf)

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Not really. That question you suggest is a duplicate of my 2nd bullet point, which I consider moot because of the explanation I gave of circuit breakers.

Comment: "Assuming the asset recovers before I am forced to liquidate, eventually losses will be overcome by gains". This is true only to the extant that your liquidity is infinite. It may appear that a large margin is the same as infinite margin, but surely that isn't the case in reality (if your need for funds was truly non-existent, then surely the need to even invest is irrelevant, right?). YTD returns on TQQQ today are -60% vs QQQ at -20%. That's a tough hole to climb out from.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I guess I should do a better job at framing the context. I'm kinda assuming that I won't *need* the money at any point. As in, this is a retirement fund for 30+ years. So not really that my liquidity is infinite, but more like I'll never need to use the funds. A -60% return is offset by a +150% return, which TQQQ has a record of doing every 2-4 years. So I'm making the assumption that 1) the money isn't pulled prematurely, and 2) the market continues its ~8-11% annual growth

Comment: @TylerM Alright I think I see the source of your confusion now, see my provided answer

Answer (score 3):

**A leveraged ETF is not suitable for long-term use!**

Moreso even than investing with your own source of leverage, a 'self-leveraged' ETF will dig itself into a hole with losses that it is difficult to climb out of.

Here is the fundamental error in the math underpinning your analysis:

> "*Any sort of loss over some period (say 10% loss over 5 stagnant
> years) will be received again by only a 3.3% upswing in the underlying
> asset. I feel like this "risk" is sort of moot*."

**The problem with this statement is that a leveraged ETF *always maintains exactly 3x leverage*, meaning following a loss, any subsequent gain is relatively minimized by the artificially reduced asset base, as the index sheds its own debt to avoid becoming '3.1x' leveraged**.

Consider - if you have a margin account which you use to artificially create a '3x portfolio', and the underlying asset drops by 50%, unless you put further cash into your account, you will be left with 6x leverage, because your asset will have devalued but your original borrowed debt amount will not change. This now-increased relative leverage amount is what allows the net investment to 'catch up' to a non-leveraged alternative, when gains follow losses. VERSUS: For a 3x-leveraged ETF, after a 50% loss the leverage remains 3x, so the magnification of gains is relatively smaller than the initial magnification of losses.

**Assume 3 scenarios where an index drops 3.3% and then climbs back up a 'neutralizing' 3.41%** [*note - 3.3% down then 3.3% up nets you back to only 99.81% of your original value*]  - in the first, we show no leverage, in the 2nd, we show a 3x margin account [or similar form of personal debt taken on for investment], and in the 3rd, we show a 3x leveraged ETF.

- Scenario 1: $100 cash invested drops 3.3% to $96.7; $96.7 climbs up 3.41% to $100.
- Scenario 2: $100 cash invested + $200 borrowed funds invested, drops 3.3% to $290.1 [$90.1 equity]. $290.1 climbs back up 3.3% to $300 [$100 equity, exactly returning to the same net equity value as in a case of no leverage].
- **Scenario 3: $100 cash invested in a 3x index drops 9.9% to $90.1. $90.1 climbs up 10.23% only $99.32!** Long-term investment in a leveraged ETF account has failed us after a loss by returning poorer-than comparative results from either no leverage or a margin account, exactly as every financial guidance has warned it would.

**Now let's prove out this theory with actual results comparing TQQQ vs QQQ** https://portfolioslab.com/tools/stock-comparison/TQQQ/QQQ *[amazing to me that you haven't even looked at the differential between the assets in your question - the historical track record is immediately self-evident - be INCREDIBLY careful at becoming overconfident. Do not assume that disagreeing with everyone around you is a sign that you know better!]*

Merely using YTD values on TQQQ [down 56.11%] vs QQQ [down 17.82%], we can see that a 25% increase in the underlying would yield net gains gains for QQQ of 1.02725 [$1 * 0.8218 * 1.25]. Whereas TQQQ would still only be at 0.768% of original value, a remaining loss of 23.19% [$1 * 0.4399 * 1.75]!

In fact it's only coincidence that the YTD TQQQ loss of 56% is roughly 3x the 17.82% of the underlying. **The comparative 12 month return for each as of today is -46% for TQQQ, vs -11% loss for QQQ - that's fully 4x the loss! Why? *Because the underlying ETF effectively sheds debt after losses to maintain 3x leverage, which counterintuitively performs far worse than a self-leveraged margin account which would naturally increase its relative leverage after losses***.

**Final caveat on risk - that doesn't mean a margin account is low-risk!** Risk in finance is variance in returns, and a margin account has a higher variance in returns compared with no leverage. *Keep in mind that a margin account is not the only method to achieve personal leverage anyway - if you are a homeowner with a mortgage and also an investment account, you already implicitly are using overall financial leverage to invest, when you could instead have paid off your mortgage.*

Comment: I appreciate the use of numbers and the effort you put into the explanation. Referencing a part in your explanation, I would like to make it clear that I'm *not* arguing for the sake of arguing -- in my mind, I just see a lot of these "risks" as being entirely mitigated by proper investing practices. ...With that being said, I *did* read over your explanation thoroughly three (3) times, to fully digest it. I still have issue with the "risks" presented, and I'll try to outline it as best as I can very soon.

Comment: @TylerM Forget the math that gets there - follow the link I offered to a data source showing the tracking of those two indices - they diverge over time, which is a natural, mathematic consequence of having a random walk of losses followed by gains. A leveraged ETF is simply not equivalent to personal leverage on the same asset. It simply will not recover from significant losses. It is not intended to - it is intended in theory for short term trades only.

Comment: ITYM "your original borrowed debt amount will >>not<< change"

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks, fixed!\

Answer (score 0):

Financial products should be "used as directed," unless you are an experienced finance pro. It's best to take the warning on the [TQQQ webpage](https://www.proshares.com/funds/tqqq.html) seriously, and avoid the product for long-term investment:

> ProShares' returns over periods other than one day will likely differ
> in amount and possibly direction from the target return for the same
> period

Long-term leverage for ordinary investors is still a dream, if not a pipe-dream, despite the obvious benefits. The authors of *[Lifecycle Investing](http://lifecycleinvesting.net/book.html)* advocate that young people lever up 50% by using the full margin privileges in a taxable brokerage account. But this means forgoing the tax benefits of an IRA. Leverage is not allowed in IRAs.

Comment: Can you provide a source stating that the leveraged ETFs are not allowed in an IRA? I currently have a portion of my Roth IRA invested into TQQQ.

Comment: As you pointed out, ProShares protects its self from liability by stating that the returns on any given period will *almost certainly* not be the same leverage as what it tracks *daily*. This is fine though, as it is what causes the highs to be *so high* due to the compounding. I don't see it as a risk, rather it describes the nature of how the fund behaves.

Comment: Sorry i think i misunderstood -- you are saying the authors recommend buying on margin, which is not allowed in IRA - correct?

Comment: @TylerM That's right. You can't use direct margin in IRAs, but you absolutely can access leverage via these ETFs.