# Why TSL2 is not exact double of TSLA? (Tesla stock)

Tags: stock-markets

I am analysing these stock options. One is Tesla (TSLA) and the other is Tesla with x2 leverage (TSL2).

I am quite surprise to found that TSL2 is not double of TSLA. It seems to be more or less correlated, but not an exact x2. For example, today, one is rising and the other is falling.

Why is this?

tesla stock today

[image]

tsl2 stock today

[image]

Comment: I think you have posted the wrong screenshots. Both screenshots show TSL2.

Comment: Note that "stock options" has a different meaning than what you probably intended. Also note that "actions" in some continental European languages is "stock" in English.

Comment: fixed the first screenshot, thx

Comment: Are you aware that in your screenshots, one is shown in USD and the other is priced in Euro?

Comment: Related: [Understanding downside of triple-leveraged ETF](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/51821/10997)

Comment: Also note that a 2X leveraged ETF (or ETP in this case) is not necessarily 2 times the _price_ of the underlying stock or index. It means that the _daily returns_ will be twice that of the stock. So you should not expect a 2X leveraged TSLA ETP to be twice the _price_ of TSLA, but have twice the _return_ each day.

Comment: 451 USD is roughly 427 EUR on April 27, 2022.

Comment: Also, there is a 6 hour time difference between New York and Paris.

Answer (score 2):

If it would be always exactly double the price, its whole existence would be useless - you could just buy two shares of the underlying.
The whole point of the existence is that you can buy something that promises twice the *relative* movement of the underlying, which implies that its price cannot have a constant ratio - it has to move double as fast.

Answer (score 0):

**Stock + Option (Leverage) is not the same as Stock + Stock**

Because the leveraged stock has stocks and options to get the 2x leverage.  An option is not the same as a stock.  It means someone has agreed to sell or buy a stock at a certain price during a certain window of time.

The cause of the price difference is the value of the options.  An option's value doesn't depend on stock price, but on time window and stock price relative to the option.  You're seeing the difference here.